# Tom Misch - It Runs Through Me Theory Question

Tags: theory

I have a question regarding the chord progression for It Runs Through Me and how it works from a theory standpoint.

It seems to be in the key of Bm. With the chord progression going something like [Bm7 -> D7sus2 -> Gmaj7 ->B/F# ->Bb aug?]. The last chord is up for debate. A couple of chords are not diatonic, like D7sus2 which looks like a secondary dominant to me.

But I'm not sure how he fits in B/F# and Bb aug? How do these chords fit in to the key? Chord substitution?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a listen and it sounds to me like the chords on the chorus are

```
Bm7  | D7sus4 | Gmaj7 | C#m7b5 F#7#9
```

which you seem well-equipped to analyze on your own. The bassist occasionally plays a C on the final chord, creating a `C13` sound (a tritone substitution: notice that the shell voicings for `F#7#9` and `C13` are identical).

On the verses, he substitutes `B/C#` for the `C#7b5`, which you can think of as a hollowed-out `C#m11` (without the third and fifth), itself an embellishment of `ii7` borrowed from the parallel major. The guitar voicing is `x4x442`, as you can see in this screenshot at 2:02:

[image]

Playing a `B` triad over a `C#` root in a `C#m7` context is a common guitarist trick. It lets you incorporate the upper extensions of the `C#m11` chord without the muddiness (and fingering challenges) that can occur when the minor third is present.

Meanwhile, substituting `ii7` for `ii7b5` in a minor key is a common flourish in bossa nova because it allows you to create chromatic motion in a middle voice: here G♯, the fifth of `C#m11` → G♮, the ♭9 of `F#7b9` → F♯, the fifth of `Bm`. This guitarist didn't choose voicings that do this, but that possibility may help explain why the borrowed `ii7` is relatively common in this genre.

Comment: I got a chance to work this out a little more at my instrument and have added a screenshot of the suspect chord. Take a look, @jrock, and see if this answers your question, and thanks for showing us a cool tune!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that B/F♯ is, in context, an attempt to pull off a I 6/4 of iv - a tonicization of the subdominant.

Then we learn that's abortive (assuming your last chord is correct) and it moves to the altered dominant of A♯aug. A♯aug works as an altered dominant chord because it contains the leading tone of B minor, A♯. (A♯aug is enharmonic with B♭aug but makes more sense in B minor.)

The B/F♯ chord's movement to A♯aug is something I cannot fully explain. The voice leading is smooth for the upper voices but a small leap for the lowest notes. Maybe a I - Valt - i feel is what's aimed for?

Comment: `B/F#` could be `I 6/4` borrowed from the parallel major, and then one might think of the `A#+` instead as a `F#+` in first inversion, `V+` being a common substitution for the dominant in minor.